# Debugging Open Dylan Debian build

Tags: debian, packaging

I'm trying to debug some *very* basic and unfinished [Debian packaging](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/opendylan-debian) for [Open Dylan](https://github.com/dylan-lang/opendylan).

I'm getting errors in the [Debian build log (gist)](https://gist.github.com/8f6df98b79a2e99e972e).

The relevant bit is at the end, namely:

```
Preparing to install Open Dylan...
Copying sources...
cp: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/sources’: Permission denied
Makefile:328: recipe for target 'install-stage' failed
```

This clearly corresponds to the lines starting at 342 in
[Makefile.in](https://github.com/dylan-lang/opendylan/blob/master/Makefile.in), namely:

```
# Install stage installs stage 3 into prefix
install-stage:
    @echo Preparing to install Open Dylan in $(prefix)...
    @install -d $(prefix)
    @echo Copying sources to $(prefix)/sources...
    @rm -rf $(prefix)/sources
    @cp -R $(abs_srcdir)/sources $(prefix)
```

Probably the last line is the culprit, but I'm having difficulty seeing what is going wrong.

It would help greatly if I could get the build to consistently echo every line before executing it, but as you can see in the extract quoted above, it didn't happen when I needed it to. Namely at that `cp` line.

NOTE: Open Dylan isn't using Automake, though they are using Autoconf. And so they have a handwritten `Makefile.in`.

UPDATE: Adding `make -n` to the `dh_auto_build` and `dh_auto_install`
overrides works. Thusly:

```
override_dh_auto_build:
        PATH=$(binpath):$$PATH make -n

override_dh_auto_install:
        PATH=$(binpath):$$PATH make -n install
```

The [new build log(gist)](https://gist.github.com/43277168912cc52fbeb4)
now has the following for the upstream Open Dylan Makefile install target:

```
echo Preparing to install Open Dylan...
install -d /usr/local
echo Copying sources...
rm -rf /usr/local/sources
cp -R /usr/local/src/opendylan/opendylan-2014.1/sources /usr/local
find /usr/local/sources -depth -name '.*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
rm -rf /usr/local/sources/bootstrap1-registry
echo Installing Open Dylan in /usr/local
install -d /usr/local/bin /usr/local/databases /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/runtime
install -d /usr/local/share/opendylan /usr/local/include/opendylan
cp -R /usr/local/src/opendylan/opendylan-2014.1/Bootstrap.3/bin /usr/local
cp -R /usr/local/src/opendylan/opendylan-2014.1/Bootstrap.3/databases /usr/local
cp -R /usr/local/src/opendylan/opendylan-2014.1/Bootstrap.3/include/opendylan /usr/local/include
# We use force here because on Mac OS X, the lib directory likely contains read-only
# static libraries for the Boehm GC.
cp -Rf /usr/local/src/opendylan/opendylan-2014.1/Bootstrap.3/lib /usr/local
cp -Rf /usr/local/src/opendylan/opendylan-2014.1/Bootstrap.3/share/opendylan /usr/local/share
cp -R /usr/local/src/opendylan/opendylan-2014.1/tools/lldb /usr/local/share/opendylan
cp -R /usr/local/src/opendylan/opendylan-2014.1/tools/bash_completion /usr/local/share/opendylan
cp /usr/local/src/opendylan/opendylan-2014.1/License.txt /usr/local
cp /usr/local/src/opendylan/opendylan-2014.1/packages/unix/README /usr/local
echo Done!
```

This is clearly all wrong from the beginning. For some reason, `prefix` here is `/usr/local`, while it should be `/debian/tmp/usr` (I think).

The first line of the [Open Dylan Makefile.in](https://github.com/dylan-lang/opendylan/blob/master/Makefile.in) has:

```
prefix          = $(DESTDIR)@prefix@
```

which looks kind of non-standard. In the generated Makefile, this becomes:

```
prefix          = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local
```

Normally Debian passes `/usr` to `./configure` by default, so I'm not sure what happened here, or why (apparently), `DESTDIR` is blank.

Answer (score 2):

The `@` before some of the lines tells make "do not echo this line".

You could edit and remove some of the `@`s or strip them all from the Makefile with:

```
sed -i -e 's/^\(\t\+)@/\1/ ; s/\(^\t\+\)echo/\1@echo/' Makefile
```

The make doc extract by @Ortomala Lokni made a good point about `echo`, so i've modified the sed script to put an `@` back before any `echo` commands.

To deal with Automake, you probably want to be a bit more careful with removing the `@` characters, Automake uses `@NAME@` to substitute variables into the ouput Makefile:

Maybe something like this, so that it doesn't change lines that begin with `\t+@NAME@`:

```
sed -ire 's/^(\t+)@([^ @]+ )/(\t)\1/ ; s/(^\t+)echo/\1@echo/' Makefile.in
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete the cas answer you can read the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing) which says:

> Normally make prints each line of the recipe before it is executed. We call this echoing because it gives the appearance that you are typing the lines yourself.
>
> When a line starts with ‘@’, the echoing of that line is suppressed. The ‘@’ is discarded before the line is passed to the shell. Typically you would use this for a command whose only effect is to print something, such as an echo command to indicate progress through the makefile:
>
> `@echo About to make distribution files`
>
> When make is given the flag ‘-n’ or ‘--just-print’ it only echoes most recipes, without executing them. See Summary of Options. In this case even the recipe lines starting with ‘@’ are printed. This flag is useful for finding out which recipes make thinks are necessary without actually doing them.
>
> The ‘-s’ or ‘--silent’ flag to make prevents all echoing, as if all recipes started with ‘@’. A rule in the makefile for the special target .SILENT without prerequisites has the same effect (see Special Built-in Target Names). .SILENT is essentially obsolete since ‘@’ is more flexible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would one pass the `-n` option via the Debian build system?

Comment: Actually, it looks like amending my override from `PATH=$(binpath):$$PATH make` to `PATH=$(binpath):$$PATH make -n` works.